# Different sha256 between nix-hash and nix-prefetch-url

Tags: nix, nixos

When I want to precompute the `sha256` of a downloaded file `foo.txt`, the output of `nix-hash` on the **manually downloaded** file is different from the one that is printed by `nix-prefetch-url`.

How can I compute the same hash with `nix-hash`?

Answer (score 0):

The standard format of `nix-hash` is different from the one that `nix-prefetch-url` uses.

To get the same output from the manually downloaded file as `nix-prefetch-url` would give, run `nix-hash` like this:

```
nix-hash --type sha256 --flat --base32 <file>
```